# React app on Safari mobile extends past 100%

Tags: css

I am having a problem where my app is extending past 100% of the window on the screen and there is some extra space hidden beneath the bottom also (it looks like the total extra space is equal to the top URL bar on Safari). Here is a screenshot of my app on my phone:

[image]

You can see that the top bar can scroll out of the window, how do I prevent that behavior? Note: It doesn't do this on Chrome mobile -- it stays within the window

Here is how I my app is rendered:

```
return(
    <div className = {classes.FullApp}>
        <TopBar toggle={this.toggleSideBar} isOpen={this.state.sidebar} logout={this.handleLogout}/>
        <main className={classes.Main}>
            {sidebar}
            {dash}
        </main>
    </div>
)
```

and here is the css that the .FullApp:

```
.FullApp{
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.Main{
    position: relative;
    height:90vh;
    width:100%;
    background-color: chocolate;
    display:flex;
    z-index:135;
}
.Side{
    width: 50vw;
}
```

TopBar CSS:

```
.TopBar{
    background-color:#49d49d;
    height:10vh;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index:175;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 42px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: You need to share some code. This is not a “React” issue, but a CSS one.

Comment: @Nate I edited it to include the main, highest-level components and their styles

Comment: Would you also be able to add the CSS for `TopBar`? I imagine it's the green thing. Is your goal for this to fit in a single page full screen with no scrollbar?

Comment: @Nate Edited. Yes the goal is for a single page, no scrollbar app